# Assigning Class to Generic attribute

Tags: java, generics

Using the wildcard Class just leads to a warning. But what is wrong with this method, I get compiler-error '...cannot convert from class SubclassX to Class'

```
public static <T extends Superclass> void createInstance(Class<T> param) {
    if (param == null) {
        if (whatever) {
            param = Subclass1.class; // Comp-Error
        } else if (whatever2) {
            param = Subclass2.class; // Comp-Error
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }
```

}

Edit:
Just to be sure, Subclass1 and Subclass2 are extending Superclass.

Comment: When the method is called `T` is supposed to be "some specific subclass of `Superclass` (that is not known at compile time)". The compiler can't know that whatever `T` is going to be will be compatible with `Subclass1` or `Subclass2`.

Comment: @khelwood: I added an edit. Is you're answer still correct? I believe, that the compiler knows, that 'class Subclass1 extends Superclass {}'.

Comment: You could only assign the `Class<T>` variable to `Subclass1.class` if the compiler _knows for sure_ that `T` is `Subclass1`. But it doesn't, because `T` could be _any_ subclass of `Superclass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T` is chosen by the compiler depending on the method call (e.g. `ContainingClass.createInstance(Subclass2.class)` means `T = Class<Subclass1>`). It's not guarantied that `Subclass1.class` (a `Class<Subclass1>`) or `Subclass2.class` (a `Class<Subclass2>`) is assignable to `Class<T>`. In fact there is no class `T` such that both would be assignable.

Comment: Thanks, that were the internals I did not know/realize.